# Any reason to avoid word "type" in Rails using Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, reserved-words

I know `type` is a [magic field name](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/MagicFieldNames) with `ActiveRecord` for use in Single Table Inheritance. But `:type` is not included in `Mongoid.destructive_fields`. Is there any reason I can't use it as a field name? `Upload.upload_type` feels so ackward and I'd much prefer to use `Upload.type`.

Furthermore `class`, `category`, and `variety` don't seem like good alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using it without any problems so far. So unless I run into any issues down the road I'm going to answer no, there's no reason to avoid using the word "type".

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoid an attribute `_type` is define to help in the STI too. So it's better to avoid using it too.

Comment: Yes, but why would `_type` interfere with `type`? In my tests so far there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that "_type" is used for STI and thus "type" is technically a valid attribute name.  It will work for your situation just fine.  I would just be cautious using those "special names", however.  If you ever switch over to a different database you will probably run into problems, but if you have control over that and know that you'll be using MongoDB, then there isn't a really good reason why you can't use the "type" field.

I personally would not use any of the special words that many databases or frameworks use, as it just makes it less-confusing for others.  But that is just a personal preference; there's no technical reason.